# Text bleeding out of the webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am having an issue with a simple webview app in Swift. I have set up most of the app, however when I test it there are two pages of the website (out about 40) which bleed out of the webview and mess up all the formatting in the app.

Normal View:
[Normal webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m72m.png)

One of the problem pages:
[problem webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtNhG.png)

I have look at a number of articles on here dealing with similar issues but none of those solutions seem to work for me.

Right now i'm using this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let aurl = NSURL(string: "http://georgetown.neotalogic.com/a/jobdefender")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: aurl! as URL)

    Webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    Webview.scalesPageToFit = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it in a quickly created demo app with

```
webview.delegate = self
webview.scalesPageToFit = true
webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
```

And couldn't reproduce the issue. Maybe the order matters or maybe you have to set the delegate to self even without implementing any delegate functions. Idk :/

[image]